# Api requests do not work on Android with EXPO

Tags: android, expo, react-native

SDK Version: **40.0.0**

Platforms: **Android **

Api requests do not work on Android,

I used **axios** and **fetch** for api requests.

I'm getting an error ( **Network Error** ) a long time after submitting a request.

Picture of the error;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5YwW.png)

I found this " android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" " for **React Native**.

How do i do this in **EXPO**.

**Note**: Certificate provided by **Let’s Encrypt**

**Thank you for your help**

Comment: I had your same problem, did you add firebase to your project? If you did not, please [read my answer in this other post:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74212344/8139569)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer

Generally speaking, any valid SSL certificate should work just fine. That also includes all lets encrypt certificates, with the only requirement that it's a valid certificate. You can use tools like SSL Labs to test the validity of your SSL certificate.

[https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12016][1]